# Web service lifetime against authentication list

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

### What I have

I'm making a web service using C#.

In order to authenticate users, they have to send their name plus their encrypted password, in order to check if exists in a database.

Then, If it's found, I create a *string token*, which is a 10 char string randomly generated in order to send it the next times while the session is alive, avoiding to have to send the original credentials anymore.

### What is my problem

Using this approach, my problem appears due to the service lifetime.

It's known that web services are not initialized each time a request arrives, but nor is infinite. So there will be a moment, when it'll be destroyed and initialized again.

At this point, my *token list* would be erased, as well as all the alive connections with it, as this is its function.

So I'm stuck at this point. I'm not sure about how to proceed, maybe I'm just fooling around and **there's a simpler way to authenticate users?** Or maybe you've and idea about how to *don't loose all these alive sessions without having to write them at a DB*.

Thank you in advance

**Update**:

### My goal

I aim to create a personal Web Service, just build for me and some friends. Not inside a company nor anything like this. Not in the same LAN neither.

I want to add a bit of security to this service, so I wanted to add authentication to the WS, mainly in order to avoid people pretending to be another and this kind of stuff. So I created User+Password system.

Then, in order to avoid to send them both in each WS Request, I started to write the "token" approach described above.

Notice that I'm using `token` word because it's similarity with token systems for these cases, but it's a completely *created from 0* system, nothing proffesional, so do not assume anything complex about it if I've not said that.

### How my system works (or try to)

```
User -> Auth (user, pass_encrypted) -> WS -> DB (exist? OK)
WS -> token (randomly generated, 10char string) -> User
```

After that, at each WS request, `User` sends the token instead of credentials.

After receiving it, WS looks for the token at a `List<structureToken>`, so it obtains the user which is doing the call, and (for example) the access level, in order to know if the user has rights to run this call.

Comment: Side note: There are no *simpler* ways to authenticate users, there are safer once... If the goal is to re-invent the wheel it is generally good idea to read about existing once - something like OAuth spec could be a good start.

Comment: Back to original Q: assuming you digitally sign the token you should not need to store it at all. So not clear why you have problem with restarts.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong @AlexeiLevenkov. Which I call _token_ is just an string. It's not signed, and even if it were, i don't understand how could this help me to know which user is without having the "token" associated with an username =S. About OAuth, I've readed a bit about it, but I wonder if there exist any other mechanism for user authentication inside the framework? Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing but strings in HTTP... So it somewhat implied that "token" is just a string (as with all other HTTP authentication schemes). If you need just user name - sign the name (don't even need full encryption - just basic SHA256 hash with salt may satisfy your security requirements if you have any)  and send it to the user (usually one includes expiration in such value).

Comment: Please consider to clarify in the post what the goal of your effort - clearly if you are building actual product and not just learning exercise then you should use existing auth (maybe even basic Windows auth would work if it is internal to some organization with Windows domain)

Comment: Updated @AlexeiLevenkov. I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you're trying to say me. Even if I build tokens by signing the user's name, this is just another way to generate a "token string", but my problem is that I've all the current users in a List, and they'll be erased when the WS is initialized again.

Comment: Yes, your problem is that you want same list to be persisted through restarts and not persisted to any physical media at the same time. You have to pick one of the choices and live with it: not persisted - just ignore the fact you can have list in memory and make sure token can be validated by itself ({SHA256(Name + "SecretSalt"), Name} is cheap and relatively secure option), if persisting - pick storage and save you list of random numbers.

Comment: I see, so the point is that it can be validated by itself. Thank you so much for all your effort @AlexeiLevenkov. If you put it as answer I'll valitade it. I take this last opportunity to ask you about the Salt. How do it usually works? I mean, should I generate it by doing a SHA256 to the password for example, then using it to concatenate it to the name and do SHA256 to the whole string then? You can answer or not directly at the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is that you want same list to be persisted through restarts and not persisted to any physical media at the same time. You have to pick one of the choices and live with it: not persisted - just ignore the fact you can have list in memory and make sure token can be validated by itself, if persisting - pick storage and save you list of random numbers.

Since you are building simple system without actual need to have proven verifiable security you can get some ideas from existing systems (like [STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Token_Service) and the way it creates token). Basically STS signs information about user (indeed after validation) and than encrypts it with public key of receiving party. So particular server that supposed to get the token can decrypt it (as it has private key part), everyone else may still use it but have to treat as non-verifiable black box token.

Simplest version of this would be no encryption of information, just basic signing. Proper signing requires private/public pair (so external party can validate signature), but since in your case both parties are the same service - you can just SHA256. To prevent external callers to fake you signature you need to have some private information included in hash to "salt" value before hashing. Random number hardcoded into server code (or read from settings) would be good enough. You may also want to include expiration as part of signed value.

So your "token" could look like:

```
Name,expiration,Base64 of SHA256 of {Name + expiration + secret value}

Bob-2015-06-30-A23BDEDDC56
```

Since your server code have "secret value" you can always re-compute hash to verify if it is indeed the correct token.

Notes:

- *do not* use it for any real services. Use an existing authentication and make sure to review all security comments related to proper usage of it.
- this approach gives you chance to learn a some other concepts - i.e. key update (when your "secret value" need to change, or in real systems signing/encryption certs).